# Using ontology URI's end up in 'error 404 not found'

Tags: sparql, ontology

I am querying the [NIFSTD ontology](https://github.com/SciCrunch/NIF-Ontology/tree/master/ttl).

I have loaded the ontology into a triple store. When clicked on some query results, they ended in 'error 404 - not found.

Then I looked into the header of ontology files and found out using all uri's related to NIFSTD ended in the same error. I have mentioned some of them below:

```
@prefix NIFEXT: <http://uri.neuinfo.org/nif/nifstd/nifext_> .
@prefix NIFRID: <http://uri.neuinfo.org/nif/nifstd/readable/> .
@prefix NIFSTD: <http://uri.neuinfo.org/nif/nifstd/> .
@prefix NLX: <http://uri.neuinfo.org/nif/nifstd/nlx_> .
@prefix NLXANAT: <http://uri.neuinfo.org/nif/nifstd/nlx_anat_> .
@prefix NLXSUB: <http://uri.neuinfo.org/nif/nifstd/nlx_subcell_> .
```

Does this mean they have moved the ontology or it is not available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, these references were moved or deleted without also performing a referential integrity check.

So the old links were not updated, or (by the look of it) were updated with the root part(s) of the URI but not the final identifying element.  Bad code